# sub graph of the 10 most represented node in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I have a data frame file like below for attribute , and also I have a matrix of network like below,  I attached attribute properly to the data. but now
1-  I want the most 30 authors that are most represented in term of degree, I know that I should use subgraph, but I am not sure my code is correct or not

2- I want to authors with most citation, because I want to plot them .

can someone help me?

```
my attribute set
Code    Sector  AUTHOR  H.Index NumDocs References  Citations
<fct>   <fct>   <fct>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
S0004   SECS-S/01   AGATI P 2   6   134 32
S0005   SECS-S/01   AGOSTINELLI C   5   11  127 39
S0008   SECS-S/01   ALFO M  8   24  688 151
S0025   SECS-S/01   AREZZO MF   1   NA  NA  11
```

```
my data
      S0001 S0004   S0005   S0008   S0025   A0005   A0008   A0009
S0001   0     0      0        0      0       0        1       1
S0004   0     1      1        1      0       0        0       0
S0005   0     1      1        1      0       0        0       0
S0008   0     1      1        1      0       0        0       0
S0025   1     1      1        0      0       0        0       1
A0005   0     1      1        1      0       0        0       0
A0008   0     1      1        1      0       0        0       0
A0009   1     1      1        0      0       0        0       1
```

```
library("igraphdata")
library("igraph")
library("network")
library("statnet")
library("intergraph")

#Imagin my igraph object called PRIN_graph

#for the most represented authors:
DEG <-order(igraph::degree(PRIN_graph, mode = "all", normalized = T),decreasing = TRUE)
DEG[1:30]
HighDeg = induced_subgraph(PRIN_graph, DEG[1:30])
HighDeg

#how to get the vertex name for the most citations?
ci<- sort(unique(V(PRIN_graph)$Citations))
c<-sort(table(V(PRIN_graph)$Citations))
c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your example is not reproducible, the assumption is that you have an `igraph` object `g`, with a vertex attribute `citations` (see data below). Also, the top 10 nodes are selected instead of 30. You can easily change that.

You can simply pass in a logical vector to the `induced_subgraph` command, which is used to subset the nodes. You can get such a vector by combining `rank`, which also helps you dealing with possible ties in the rank, and `<`. It is a bit unclear what your preferences for ties are, I assume that if two or more observations match rank 10 then you keep both of them. The alternative would be to keep the first or the last, or to select one at random (check out `ties.method` for `rank`).

```
g.s <- induced_subgraph(g, rank(-V(g)$citations) < 11 )

get.vertex.attribute(g.s, "citations")
[1] 16 11 12 16 11  9  9 13 13 14 12

get.vertex.attribute(g.s, "label")
[1] "id1"  "id4"  "id6"  "id7"  "id10" "id12" "id13" "id15" "id17" "id19" "id20"
```

As you can see, a graph with the top 10 cited people was is returned. Note that at rank 10 there are two observations with value 9, therefore in total we have 11 nodes.

You can do exactly the same using degree. First add the degree to the list of attributes, and then subset on it:

```
V(g)$degree <- degree(g)
g.s <- induced_subgraph(g, rank(-V(g)$degree) < 11 )
```

Data:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(123)
n <- 20
p <- 0.5
g <- random.graph.game(n, p)

# att attributes
V(g)$label <- paste0("id",1:n)
V(g)$citations <- rpois(n, 10)

vertex.attributes(g)

$label
 [1] "id1"  "id2"  "id3"  "id4"  "id5"  "id6"  "id7"  "id8"  "id9"  "id10" "id11"
[12] "id12" "id13" "id14" "id15" "id16" "id17" "id18" "id19" "id20"

$citations
 [1] 16  5  6 11  5 12 16  5  2 11  6  9  9  4 13  8 13  6 14 12
```